# ORMLite and Lollipop

Tags: android

This code not working in smartphone with android version 5.0.2

```html
@Override
 public List<Client> searchAll() throws Exception {
  return getHelper().getClientDao().queryForAll();// Here the problem
 }
```

No error is returned.
The application only stopped.
I'm using ormLite

Comment: If application is stopped the error has to occurs Post your logcat

Comment: Remove your post is redundant when you want to add log you jus update your question

Comment: I mean post below. Additionally you have to add relevant logs. The log below is not log which shows error

Comment: but No error is returned. This is a complete LogCat.

Comment: It can not be complete error. Please set filter **Log Level : Error** and in the spinner set **No Filters** And run your application and call the crash